# Where do I need super.attached for in a custom polymer element?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm playing around a bit with custom elements and custom attributes with Polymer.dart, but I can't find out what the line `super.attached` does.

```dart
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="kp-volume">

<template>
  <p>You turned the volume to {{volume}}.</p>
</template>

<script type="application/dart">
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';

@CustomTag('kp-volume')
class KPVolume extends PolymerElement {

  KPVolume.created() : super.created();

  @published int volume = 0;

  void attached() {
    //where do I need this line for ?
    super.attached();
    volume = 5;
  }
}
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

So I get that if I change the volume in the `attached` function, that then I can override HTML code like this `<kp-volume volume="11"></kp-volume>`. But there doesn't seem to be a difference in using `super.attached` or not. What does this line do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attached` is a method in the super class `PolymerElement` which does the actual attaching of the element to the DOM.

If you override the method in a subclass the `attached` method of the super class is disable and therefore the element will never be attached.

By overriding a method you replace it's default implementation.

By calling `super.attached()` you invoke the default implementation in `PolymerElement` and reuse the default implementation in your replacement.

You can add your custom code before or after the `super.attached()` line so your custom code will be execute before and/or after the default attach logic.

Overriding `attached` and not calling `super.attached();` will break your element. Maybe your example element is just too simple to notice.

Other lifecycle methods like `ready`, `domReady` don't need the call to the super implementation because the default implementation is an empty function. 
(`xxxChanged` lifecyle methods are yet another kind, they don't exist in the super class at all).